# How to create a link to a lightbox gallery popup?

Tags: wordpress, gallery, lightbox

I'm trying to have a normal hyperlink opening up a lightbox like gallery

The only thing I've found so far are workarounds which involve coding, but then it's not at all user friendly for my customer.

Isn't any plugin out there which provides a lightbox gallery popup as link?

Comment: Are you using wordpress theme??

Answer (score 1):

If you would be using fancybox, then it would be as easy as adding `data-fancybox` attribute to the trigger elements (e.g., links). Example: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#images-1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress theme then you can using plugin in wordpress theme.

**You can follow the plugin link for [Lightbox Gallery Popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/)**